# ELKI hierarchical clustering - "mrg_" Cluster object

Tags: machine-learning, cluster-analysis, data-mining, hierarchical-clustering, elki

I'm using `ELKI's SimplifiedHierarchyExtraction` with `AnderbergHierarchicalClustering`, `LatLngDistanceFunction` and `minClSize = 100`.

I saw that beside the `"clu_" Clusters` there are also 2 -3 `"mrg_" Clusters` which have some `DBID's`, but the number of it is `< minClSize`.

My question is: what is the best way to handle this `"mrg_" Clusters?`:

- passing its `DBID´s` to one of its `"clu_" children`?
- taking them as `a cluster` although they are under the `minClSize`?
- simply ignoring them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a *hierarchical* result.

You need to include all *child clusters* into a cluster.

So the `mrg_` cluster has some (potentially 0) new objects, *plus* all those objects in child clusters. In particular, it can have more than one child cluster (that is why it is called *merge*)

Comment: so you mean that if I have a `mrg_` which contains 4 `DBID's` and has 2 children: `one clu_ and another one mrg_`, then I should consider a cluster composed out of all the `clu_` children of `mrg_` and his `mrg_ child`?

Comment: Yes. All objects from all children also belong to this cluster. We do not store redundant memberships.

Comment: but if I do this, then I'll end up with a small number of clusters.

Comment: But I have to do this "merging" only for the 'mrg_' clusters which contain 'min 1 DBID's', am I wrong?

Comment: It is a hierarchical result. Do not expect to be able to flatten it and retain all properties. If you do all merges, everything will be in a single root. You need to treat it as a tree, where one cluster is a part of another.